# PHP Regex preg_match: Unknown modifier

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a function that allows a string only certain characters, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
$passRegex = '/[^A-Za-z0-9!\";#\$%&\'\(\)\*\+,-\./\:;<=>\?@\[]^_`\{\|}]/';

if(preg_match($passRegex, $str)) // invalid
```

But it throws

```
Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\'
```

This is the char list I want to allow:

```
!\";#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: you need to escape the `/` inside the character class

Comment: `/[~[^A-Za-z0-9!";#\$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@^_`{|}\]\-\\]/`